# jScroll save scroll position when returning to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using jQuery jScroll to give the infinite scrolling of products on our site.  How do I save the scroll position when the user returns to the index page?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a way to do this with that plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it would be to use localStorage or a cookie, and give it the value of `window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop` - which gives the current position the document is scrolled to.